# I can't delete products

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, confirm

I've been coding in the framework django for two weeks and now I am learning to delete products.

Here's the html code I've done:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


<form action = '.' method= 'POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Do you want to delete the product "{{ object.title }}"?</h1>
    <p><input type= 'submit' value = 'Yes' /> <a href='../'>Cancel</a></p>
</form>



{% endblock %}
```

And the function I've coded to delete the product

```
def product_delete_view(request, my_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id = my_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request,"products/product_delete.html", context)
```

Here's my url path:

```
path('products/<int:my_id>/delete', product_delete_view, name= 'product-delete')
```

However, my product doesn't get deleted.

Comment: your view takes the argument `my_id`, but you don't pass it from the form

Comment: @Paolo bad practice but it should work if he submitts the form because he is using the current url.
What do you mean it does not get deleted? The object should be removed from the db, however it is possibe that django holds the model instance one last time as you first fetched it from db and then deleted it. Redirecting or refreshing the page should show the product is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting somewhere after the deletion is complete, as the delete command deletes it from the database but if their as an instance in python live it will stay on until the page is either reloaded or left.